# C# Label maker application question from a novice

Tags: c#, sqlite, class, reference, structure

My retail company uses a comparatively simple label printer application that has some tables of selections to choose from and how many.

There are two classes in question. One PrintLabels class has a variable called WeekNum which states the current week number of the year. Another class which is public class DiscountService, contains the currentColorCode variable (6 colors. 1 color per week cycle.

How would I even go about referring to the WeekNum variable from the DiscountService class so that I can initialize a starting point for the color beginning on X week? (This is all due to constrain on our app not knowing what color of the week is when closing app after selecting a DIFFERENT color that is out of rotation. If you open app after, it shows the wrong color since our dat file has already been updated)

From DiscountService class:

```
public int CurrentColorCode
        {
            get
            {
                return currentColorCode;
            }
            set
            {
                // Ensure the color code is in range
                if (value < colorList.Count)
                {   scheduledColor = 
                    currentColorCode = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentColorCode = colorList.Count;
                }
            }
        }
```

From PrintLabels class:

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
            //DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
            //DayOfWeek firstday = DayOfWeek.Monday;
            //CalendarWeekRule rule = CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek;

            //Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
            //int WeekNum = cal.GetWeekOfYear(d, rule, firstday);
            DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;

            DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
            Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
            int WeekNum = cal.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
            if (WeekNum > 52)
            {
                DateTime newYear = d.AddDays(7);
                int newYearWeekNum = cal.GetWeekOfYear(newYear, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
                if (newYearWeekNum == 2)
                {
                    WeekNum = 1;
                }
            }
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(generateBarcode(barcodeString),58, 50);
```

Any help would surely be appreciated! Thank you

see note.............................................

Comment: You should remove all your tags from your question except `C#`; the others have no relevance. You should add a tag for the UI _framework_ you are using (my guess is WinForms). You will need to add more code to your question. Showing a color property and some (seemingly unrelated) print code doesn't tell us anything that we can use to understand your app. How do you persist the weekly color? How does you app's print code get invoked and how does it fit into the app?

Comment: There are 52 weeks in a year (though sometimes you will likely end up with 53). Neither of those numbers is divisible by 6, though 48 and 54 are. If you can live with not a full rotation of the colors in December, you can just have an array of 6 colors, and index into it using `(weekNumber - 1) % 6`.